# Find last site in sharepoint URL

Tags: sharepoint

So I am trying to find the last site in a URL for sharepoint. I want to be able to copy and paste a URL into a field and have it strip everything after the site.

Sharepoint URL Example 1: (always different)- http://lobportal-iceo.mysite.com/sites/wig/Support/Lists/Queue/test%20tickets.aspx

In the above example, the last site would be "support" so it should give me http://lobportal-iceo.mysite.com/sites/wig/Support when pasted in a field

Sharepoint example URL 2: http://lobportal-iceo.mysite.com/sites/wig/Support/SupportCenter/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx
So the last site in this URL is SupportCenter

The thing is, it will always change because there may be 1 or 10 subsites

This is what I have

url = url.indexOf("/Lists") >= 0 ? url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/Lists")) : url;
   url = url.indexOf("/Documents") >= 0 ? url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/Documents")) : url;
   url = url.indexOf("/View") >= 0 ? url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/View")) : url;